# Unable to run the .exe file (erro: 0xc0000279)

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, intel-oneapi, imsl

I try to use oneAPI command line to compile the FORTRAN.f90 file. The Fortran code can be compiled successfully. However, I cannot run the .exe file. Every time I run the .exe file, the error shows up and it says: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000279). I attached the snapshot here.

The Fortran code comes from the IMSL package example code. I can compile it and run it smoothly on my old computer. However, I cannot run it on my new computer. I got the license from the IMSL team and it should work. I also contact the imsl team for help and they told me to run the .exe file on "dependency walker" program to point out the error. The snapshot is the output of the "dependency walker".

The IMSL team says 'based on the output of the 'dependency walker', the error comes from LIBIFPORTMD.DLL which is an Intel library.' I'm not sure what this means and how to solve it.

I tried many ways and still cannot get rid of this error.

Can someone please tell me some clues on how to solve this problem? Appreciate it very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not paste text as images, rather copy/paste the text whenever possible, with the appropriate formatting. Images are not searchable, text it.

Comment: I see. Sorry for this. I will change it.

Answer (score 2):

According to your Dependency Walker output, the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) DLLs are not installed. This is expected if you installed only the Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit, or just the Intel Fortran Compiler, as MKL is in the oneAPI Base Toolkit.

Go to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html  In the left column, select "Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library (oneMKL)". Then select either the online or offline installer for Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library for Windows.

Comment: I would assume "mkl -- latest" in the initialization script means MKL is here? It's probably not helpful, but in my install of Ifort, I can find mkl_intel_thread.2.dll, but not mkl_intel_thread.1.dll.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply. I do install the oneAPI Base Toolkit and I can see the MKL is installed on my PC. The IMSL team says the error comes from LIBIFPORTMD.DLL which is an Intel library. Do you know what it is and how to solve it?

Comment: That is a library that is part of Intel Fortran. My guess is that there's a bad version of it elsewhere on your computer, possibly installed by IMSL. Search the PC for that file - the only place it should be is under C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI (there may be more than one copy under there, that's OK.) If you find it ANYWHERE else, including under IMSL or Windows, delete it.